# Using Promise Data from Async Await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am fetching data from an API and want to store the data in a variable that I use later.  I know that using async for a function only returns a promise.  How do I use the promise data or prevent the below from returning undefined?

```
async function getActors() {
  let payload;
  var response = await fetch("https://ceamovies.azurewebsites.net/api/movies", {
    headers: {
      "Authentication": "******"
    }
  });
  let data = await response.json();
  payload = data
  return payload
}
let actorList = getActors()
console.log(actorList)
```

Comment: try let actorList = await getActors()

Comment: @baklazan `await` only works inside `aysnc` functions

Comment: use then getActors().then((yourRespnse)=>{ })

Comment: `actorList.then(console.log)`

Comment: no you can't you can return a variable but it will be wrapped around promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async await return a Promise and you need get data in `then` method

```
async function getActors() {
    let payload;
    var response = await fetch("https://ceamovies.azurewebsites.net/api/movies", {
        headers: {
            "Authentication": "******"
        }
    });
    let data = response.json();
    payload = data
    return payload
}

getActors().then(res => {
    console.log(res)
})
```

And your path didn't access `Cross-Origin Request`

Answer (score 1):

Top level await is not supported (and for valid reasons), and thus you cannot bring your `payload` to the gloabl scope. You either need to use a promise like *Vadim H* mentioned or use another `aysnc` function to retrieve your data:

```
async function getActors() {
    let payload;
    var response = await fetch("https://ceamovies.azurewebsites.net/api/movies", {
        headers: {
            "Authentication": "******"
        }
    });
    let data = response.json();
    payload = data
    return payload
}

(async () => { // IIFE
  let actorList = await getActors();
  console.log(actorList);
})().catch(e => {
    // Something went wrong - do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A promise can be pending, fulfilled or rejected (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise)). If you want to handle rejected promises you can use `try...catch`. Like this

```
async function getActors() {
  try {
    let payload;
    var response = await fetch("https://ceamovies.azurewebsites.net/api/movies", {
        headers: {
            "Authentication": "******"
        }
    });
    let data = await response.json();
    payload = data
    return payload
  } catch(error) {
    // Do something to handle error gracefully
    // and maybe return a meaningful value.
  }
}
let actorList = getActors()
console.log(actorList)
```

If what you want to do is handle a fulfilled promise which returns `undefined` I suggest you do that outside of your `async` function, something like

```
let actorList = getActors()
if(typeof actorList !== 'undefined')
    console.log(actorList)
```